# Skip specific row when reading unpartitioned csv file in pyspark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, gzip

I have an unpartitioned gzipped csv file that I'm reading into spark. Reading in the gzipped file is not a problem but as soon as the spark dataframe is evaluated using an operation that touches one particular offending row an error is thrown out. If I use `df.limit()` I can subset the dataframe on read to the row number of the row before the offending observation and can subsequently continue my workflow without error.

My question is, is there a way to skip reading in an observation(s). I'd like to do something along the lines of df.limit_range(100:200) where rows 100-200 are skipped when reading the csv. I tried various attempts at generating an index column and then filtering but I've run into problems at the point of evaluation. Below I tried subseting to all rows before the offending row then anti joining with the original unfiltered dataframe but once evaluated the offending row causes an error once more indicating that the gzipped file cannot be read in.

```
df_full = df.withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())
df_head = df_full.limit(100).where(col("rowID") < 99)
anti_df = df_full.join(df_head, "id", "left_anti")
```

The error:

```
FileReadException: Error while reading file s3a://some-s3-bucket/dir/subdir/file_name.gz.
Caused by: EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter on the column to read all except rows 100-200.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df_full = df.withColumn("rowId", f.monotonically_increasing_id())
anti_df = df_full.filter("rowId <= 100 or rowId >= 200")
```

The output of the `anti_df` will be:

```
+----+-----+
|   z|rowId|
+----+-----+
     :
     :
|3.38|   95|
| 3.4|   96|
|4.07|   97|
|3.56|   98|
|3.66|   99|
|3.65|  100|
|3.43|  200|
|3.49|  201|
|3.48|  202|
| 3.6|  203|
|4.08|  204|
|3.63|  205|
     :
     :
```

Just make sure that your filter gets pushed down in your spark plan. By this I mean, that the filter should be executed right after the read instead of after performing several computations on it (at which point your code may fail with the offending error).